# How to step-into, step-over and step-out with GDB?

Tags: debugging, programming, gdb

I typed `help` while I was in the GDB but didn't find anything about step-into, step-over and step-out. I put a breakpoint in an Assembly program in `_start` (`break _start`). Afterwards I typed `next` and it finished the debugging. I guess it was because it finished `_start` and didn't ***step-into*** as I wanted.

Comment: Read the full GDB docs.  As I recall, they were quite helpful about this, when I was first learning it.  Unfortunately, I haven't needed to debug any program at that level for several decades, so the actual commands seem to have gotten swapped out in my brain.  So, I can't really write an answer.  But, if you do figure it out from the manuals, then you can answer your own question for a bonus.

Comment: @MAP I'll try again. I tried to use a better debugger (KDbg) but [I don't succeed to use it in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/802105/when-i-run-the-debugger-failed-to-set-controlling-terminal).

Comment: gdb _is_ a good debugger.  You may want to use Emacs as its frontend.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`help running` provides some hints:

There are `step` and `next` instuctions (and also `nexti` and `stepi`).

```
(gdb) help next
Step program, proceeding through subroutine calls.
Usage: next [N]
Unlike "step", if the current source line calls a subroutine,
this command does not enter the subroutine, but instead steps over
the call, in effect treating it as a single source line.
```

So we can see that `step` steps *into* subroutines, but `next` will step *over* subroutines.

The `step` and `stepi` (and the `next` and `nexti`) are distinguishing by "line" or "instruction" increments.

```
step -- Step program until it reaches a different source line
stepi -- Step one instruction exactly
```

Related is `finish`:

```
(gdb) help finish
Execute until selected stack frame returns.
Usage: finish
Upon return, the value returned is printed and put in the value history.
```

A lot more useful information is at https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html

Comment: What does it mean by *until it reaches a different source line*?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<10;i++) { printf("%d\n",i); }` is one source line but multiple instructions.

Comment: Is there a way to step-out?  I couldn't find it in help running.

Comment: What do you mean by "step-out"?   The `finish` command will complete the current stack frame, which will normally complete the current subroutine and return to the caller.

Comment: @PichiWuana gdb will step through as many assembly instructions as necessary until the first instruction representing the next line of source code is reached

Comment: `finish` or `fin` in GDB, is the `step-out` in `IDEA` or `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 8):

Use command 'finish'; this sometimes does the same thing as 'step-out'. It'll finish what the stack is doing (a function, usually), and go to the next line after that. Look up the command for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I came here because I had the same question. I eventually figured that for my purpose any time I could use something like "step-out" of a loop I can just set another breakpoint after the loop and then let the program `continue` to finish the loop and run into the breakpoint afterward. Sorry if that is obvious to most people but it is probably helpful for someone looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: "Step out" in most other debuggers is "finish" in gdb. Not really to do with exiting a loop.

Comment: I think that's the `until` command that you ought to use for that.